# std::get not a member of std::fstream

Tags: c++, filestream

So I'm getting an error with g++ saying that std::get is not a member of fstream. It's giving me an error particularly when i use file.get.

This is the function that is giving me the error.

```
 std::fstream& Obj::load(std::fstream& file){

            file.open("123.txt", ios::in);
            char name[30];

            file.std::get(name, 30, ","); //This line gives an error
            name(name);//sets name
            file.ignore();
            //more code for reading in omitted for sake of simplicity

            file.close();
            return file;
    }
```

The error seemed a bit nonsensical to me because std::get is a member of fstream which is derived from istream isn't it?

Comment: `std::get` is not a member if fstream, `get` is.

Comment: Are you sure that `std::get` is a member and not `fstream::get`?..

Comment: Why do you call `file.ignore()`, etc. without `std::` and decide to only use `std::` with `get`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 file.std::get(name, 30, ',');
```

With

```
file.get(name, 30, ',');
```

Your compiler is right about that, [std::get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/get/) is not a member of fstream, but [istream::get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) is usable for fstream since it's inherited !

Comment: As usual, downvoters, leave a comment explaining what should be improved.